# How do I retrieve callRecords or logs for calls made to Microsoft Teams Phone System Call Queues?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-cloudcommunications

We have recently introduced Microsoft Teams **Phone System** with **Direct routing** in our company.
We have set up a **Call Queue** for our front desk number to be able to be picked up by free users.
We want to obtain information on these calls for integration into our CRM to log phone activity with customers.

I am using a Change Notification Subscription to `/communications/callRecords` and `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/communications/callRecords/{id}` to obtain records of calls made through Teams, and in particular, the Teams Phone System.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0)

I now do receive change notifications for callRecords of calls made and received from all users.

However, I do not receive callRecords of calls made to the Call Queue.
I only receive callRecords of calls that a user assigned to the call queue has picked up.
In particular, unanswered calls to the call queue seem to show up nowhere in any log or callRecord.

Therefore my question is:
Is there any way to retrieve callRecords (or any other kind of log) for calls made to our call queue, or more general, to numbers assigned to our Resource Accounts?

So far the only information I found seems to suggest that this is a missing feature since 2018.
https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/35920921-basic-reports-and-call-lists-for-queues-and-aa

Comment: Glad that you filed uservoice...!!